# I can't connect my Vuejs app to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying to do this now for a while and it's getting to me. Read tutorials and everyone is doing it different from each other so no luck.

I'm trying to connect my Vue app to my Firebase backend.

I have a component called Staff.vue which has a script:

```
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'staff-list',

  data () {
    return {
      firebase.database().ref('employees').on('value').then((data) => {
        office.push(data);
      }).catch(
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      ),
      // This will pull in the data from Firebase.
      office: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (30:14)

  28 |   data () {
  29 |     return {
> 30 |       firebase.database().ref('employees').on('value').then((data) => {
     |               ^
  31 |         office.push(data);
  32 |       }).catch(
  33 |         (error) => {
```

I've also initialized firebase in my Main.js file:

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "foo",
  authDomain: "bar",
  databaseURL: "foobar",
  projectId: "barfoo",
  storageBucket: "foobarfoo",
  messagingSenderId: "blarg"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

I have no idea why it's not working. Please tell me someone had this issue and was able to find out why it did this to help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Move your `firebase'`initialization in one of hook, such as mounted or created.In your model, just keep data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly trying to execute code in the returned object definition.

Pull that firebase call out of the `data` method object, and call it in the `created` lifecycle hook (referencing the `office` array via `this.office`):

```
data() {
  return {
    office: []
  }
},
created() {
  firebase.database().ref('employees').on('value').then((data) => {
    this.office.push(data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! It would have kept me up all night wondering why it wasn't working! So that ran (thank god) but I'm getting the error **Error in created hook: "Error: Query.on failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.** Is that due to a firebase method or my doing. Vague question sorry.

Comment: I think I managed it actually. Just trying to find out the JSON objects and what to look for :). If it works I'll use this answer :)